# Order by other table and field on the same table

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

I have a datagridview in VB.Net that looks like this.

[image]

and my code for that is this:

```
select ItemCode,Description,DeliveryDate,StockOnHand,Format(OrderingLevel,2),OrderQty,ApprovedQty,UoM,UnitPrice,Total,Remarks,CriticalLevel,Category from purchreq INNER JOIN category ON purchreq.Category = category.CatDescription where PRNumber = '" & Data ID & "' order by purchreq.OrderQty,Category.CategoryID,purchreq.ItemCode,OrderQty;
```

before you get confused about the code the output of that is it will display the data based on my 2nd table and here it is.

[image]

for example select * from table1 order by table2 where Table1.Column1 = Table2.Column1

something like that.

Here is my question, there is a point that i will edit the data and i will edit its `Order Qty`, my question is that how can i move the data to the top? I mean all the data that has a data on column `Order Qty` will move to top and the rest of the data will go down and maintain on there first structure

For Example

[image]

I hope you get my point TYSM for future help.

Comment: select ItemCode,Description,DeliveryDate,StockOnHand,Format(OrderingLevel,2),OrderQty,ApprovedQty,UoM,UnitPrice,Total,Remarks,CriticalLevel,Category from purchreq INNER JOIN category ON purchreq.Category = category.CatDescription where PRNumber = '" & Data ID & "' order by OrderQty desc;    this is u will try

Comment: Not the output as i expected sir.